# Scala type inference ignoring provided type in package object

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-parameter, scala-2.11

I've create a DSL that is parameterised by a type parameter `Row`

```
trait ExtractorSyntax[Row] {
  def extract[A1, A2](e1: Extractor[Row, A1], e2: Extractor[Row, A2]) =
    new Tuple2Extractor[Row, A1, A2](e1, e2)

  def extract[A1, A2, A3](e1: Extractor[Row, A1], e2: Extractor[Row, A2], e3: Extractor[Row, A3]) =
    new Tuple3Extractor[Row, A1, A2, A3](e1, e2, e3)

  // More implementations
}
```

When using this you mix in `ExtractorSyntax` specifying the `Row` type. e.g.

```
import java.sql.ResultSet

class MyExtractors extends ExtractorSyntax[ResultSet] {
  val extractor1: Extractor[ResultSet, String] = ???
  val extractor2: Extractor[ResultSet, Int] = ???
  val extractor3: Extractor[ResultSet, String] = ???

  // This works fine
  val myExtractor = extract(extractor1, extractor2, extractor3)
}
```

Another way of using it is to create an object extending ExtractorSyntax and import it:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet

object MyExtractorSyntax extends ExtractorSyntax[ResultSet]

import MyExtractorSyntax._

class MyExtractors {
  val extractor1: Extractor[ResultSet, String] = ???
  val extractor2: Extractor[ResultSet, Int] = ???
  val extractor3: Extractor[ResultSet, String] = ???

  // This works fine
  val myExtractor = extract(extractor1, extractor2, extractor3)
}
```

However if you decide to extend a package object with it then it fails to compile

```
// File 1
package test

import java.sql.ResultSet

object `package` extends ExtractorSyntax[ResultSet]

// File 2
package different

import test._

class MyExtractors {
  val extractor1: Extractor[ResultSet, String] = ???
  val extractor2: Extractor[ResultSet, Int] = ???
  val extractor3: Extractor[ResultSet, String] = ???

  // This fails to compile
  val myExtractor = extract(extractor1, extractor2, extractor3)
}
```

Unfortunately at this point compilation fails with the same error for each extractor:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : sqlest.extractor.Extractor[java.sql.ResultSet,String]
[error]  required: sqlest.extractor.Extractor[Row,?]
[error]   val myExtractor = extract(extractor1, extractor2, extractor2)
[error]                             ^
```

This is strange as `ResultSet` has been specified as the type parameter for `ExtractorSyntax` and yet the compiler is asking for a `Row`.

What's going on here?

Comment: Probably it just does not handle well the overloading. Do you see problems when there is no overloading for `extract`?

Comment: Maybe provide more details surrounding `Extractor` and `TupleNExtractor` ? I tried making some dummy implementations with the same type parameters and `MyExtractors` compiles just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to create a cut down example but as you say it compiles. The point where it goes wrong is where you try to extend a package object with it and import the package. I've updated the question to reflect this